# create action,habtm relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, has-and-belongs-to-many

*please i need help
this is recipe model:*

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base

  mount_uploader :cover, AvatarUploader
  belongs_to :user

  has_and_belongs_to_many :ingredients,:join_table => 

"ingredients_recipes"

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients

end
```

*and this is Ingredient Model*

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :recipes,:join_table => "ingredients_recipes"
end
```

*i stuck in the creation action*

```
def create
    #@ingredient = Ingredient.find(params[:ingredients][:id])

    @ingredients = Ingredient.where(:id => params[:recipe][:ingredients])
    @recipe = Recipe.new(params.require(:recipe).permit(:name,:instructions,:cover,:user_id,:ingredients))
    #params[:ingredients].each_pair do |k,v|
    @recipe.ingredients << @ingredients
    #end
    #@recipe = current_user.recipes.new(params.require(:recipe).permit(:name,:instructions,:cover,:user_id, ingredients: [:id, :title] ))
    @recipe.cover = params[:cover]
    #@recipe.user_id = current_user.id
    @recipe.save
    render 'show', status: 201
  end
```

*the url comes from the Front End(Angularjs) look like this :*

```
{"recipe":{"name":"hdfndhs","instructions":"lsls,dndcj","ingredients":[{"id":2,"title":"oeuf"}]}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your problem is you cannot get correct `@ingredients`.

Please try this code to fetch `@ingredients`:

```
@ingredients = Ingredient.where(:id => params[:recipe][:ingredients].map {|ingredient| ingredient[:id]})
```

Comment: one more thing , i got
'NoMethodError (undefined method `ingredients' for nil:NilClass):'
after this,
'@recipe.ingredients << @ingredients'